# How to determine why my pixel 3a running android 12 just beeped, and stop the unexplained beeping

Tags: notifications, android-12

My cell phone has a habit of beeping, with no recent notification present either on the lock screen or on the screen you get when you swipe down from the top of a home screen. (Sorry, I don't know what that screen is called.)

Casual investigation showed no way to find out why it just beeped, and three different screens showing different (inconsistent) sets of recent notifications - one of them showing only what time each app had last produced a notification, with no content.

One of these three lists distinguished between silent and non-silent notifications.

I was unable to find any interface that controlled what kind of notifications a given app could generate. The best I could do was a binary control for whether they could generate notifications at all.

I don't want to be interrupted by beeps without any associated notification I know how to find. I'd *prefer* to be able to get notifications, with beeps, from a selected small set of apps (calendar, text messages). Ideally, I'd prefer to apply more detailed controls (my podcast player need not tell me about automatic downloads, but I'd like to know about download failures). But given the (ahem) user friendly design, I'll settle for shutting up the random beeps, even if it means I can't get audible notifications from other apps; I do however require an audible ring for phone calls, so permanent do-not-disturb-mode is not an option.

Note that I'd be overjoyed to RTFM. Pointers to documentation will be gratefully welcomed. But from experience, Android vendors routinely customize the UI, such that a manual for e.g. a Samsung might well require me to interact with UI elements not present on a pixel running the same Android version. Also, Android 12 "made Android fun again" (according to one reviewer) by making major unexplained UI changes, as well as breaking existing functionality. So I fear that a manual for an earlier Android release will just tease me with instructions to do things no longer possible.

Comment: Guess your device has the Google apps (Playstore etc) installed? I saw that with one such device I had here a while ago. Took me quite some weeks to pin-point the culprit – and it was auto-updates being installed via Play. You could try to "silence" related apps one by one via *settings › apps* – like Play Store, download manager. I cannot remember which one finally did it. And yeah, that "fun" of breaking things has a long tradition – at least back to the times of 2.x from where I remember it still…

Comment: Aha - that also answers the question of how to control app notifications in more detail. You look for Apps, select each individual app, and look for notifications within that, so settings doesn't take you there if you search for notifications.

Comment: Nope, else it would turn up each single app you've installed. And the trouble with those "update notifications" in my case was they were "audio only" and thus left no "visible trace". I can't remember what brought me on the track – probably the fact that it was the only device with GApps on it and the other devices didn't have that problem (I usually run my devices Google-free; that one was a simple test device).